# Do there exist smoke detectors with detached silencers?

Tags: kitchens, smoke-detectors

I'm looking to replace a smoke detector for my kitchen, and I was wondering whether anyone had designed a smoke detector with a remote silence feature. The traditional method of keeping a stool or a broomstick around to silence the smoke detector whenever you're cooking bacon seems pretty terrible to me, and ideal would be to have some sort of wired switch that could be mounted at shoulder height that would allow a temporary silencing of the alarm.

So far I've seen that mounting it at least 10 feet away from appliances and using a photoelectric sensor instead of an ionization sensor helps, but it would still be very nice to have some way of dealing with false alarms that doesn't involve trying to press a button twelve feet above the ground.

Comment: I don't know if it is universal, but almost every smoke alarm that I've used has this feature; pressing the button will temporarily silence the alarm.  Some alarms have two buttons, one for silence, and one for test, but most that I've used will share the button. See https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51K3GFIsb8L._SX679_.jpg on https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000MXJ498 for example.

Comment: I think I need to update my smoke detectors...

Comment: I don't see this as a feature manufacturers will add... You are in your bedroom and someone is burning their food. You remotely silence the alarm.. This happens often, what happens if it is a real fire?

Comment: @Gunner you may be right -- the use case I had in mind was just a button near the smoke alarm itself, so the chances of suppressing a true alarm is small. If there is a real alarm, you're likely to see that the kitchen is on fire when you're pressing the button. Owain's answer, below, seems to indicate that the feature exists in some form (I've seen it before, now that I think about it, in commercial fire alarm annunciators).

Comment: I have in the past seen smoke detectors with an IR remote sensor.  Pointing almost any type of remote control at the device was supposed to be able to silence it.  Note that infra red remote controls pulse the LED on and off at a rate somewhere around 40,000 times/second (varies depending upon the exact model); while a fire might emit lots of infra red, it would not be pulsed pulse in such fashion.  I have no idea how well such devices worked, or whether they are still available.

Answer (score 2):

They exist in the UK. This remote switch enables you to test all alarms, locate an activated alarm (silences all non-activated alarms), and silence false alarms.

https://www.aico.co.uk/product/ei1529rc-hard-wired-alarm-control-switch/

Any type of smoke detector is usually inappropriate for a kitchen and a heat detector is usually used, with a smoke detector in the hall outside the kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

This is really close to a shopping question which is off topic. But, the term you need to look for is [smart smoke detector](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/best-smart-smoke-detectors,review-4472.html). These are internet capable devices and some of them can be managed as an I[oT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) device.

Comment: This is the closest I've seen to supporting this use case; but the idea of having to bring up an app to stop the alarm sounds as bad as the broom stick, and configuring some crazy IFTTT logic to hook up an IoT button to the silence functionality seems fraught. Seems like this should just be a matter of taking the wires to the button and making them longer, but I'm sure there's a fire code reason why it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

There would be smoke detectors that operate both loudly and quietly for the disabled and especially hearing impaired populations where maybe a red light or a bright light is also activated so that they are aware of any heat related fires and so fourth.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't address the question of whether there is a way of remotely stopping the alarm - no matter what it's method of alerting is. Please take the [tour] to see more about how we operate here.